# Can I have an account on a node and trade with that account without the state staying on the account node?

Tags: corda

I'm working with corda accounts.
In my scenario the account is created on node M and shared with node D.
Node D runs a state creation flow, where the account is a participant.
By modeling the solution, the transaction must be registered on node D, but not on node M.
The problem is that when using the account belonging to node M, session of node M is required. And when I don't execute a ReceiveFinalityFlow on Responder Flow, an UnexpectedFlowEndException exception is generated.

And I need to be able to make a vaultquery through accountId.

The question is, can I have an account on a node and trade with that account without the state staying on the account node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `FinalityFlow` will throw an error if you don't provide a `FlowSession` for each participant (see [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L166-L168)), and in your case the account is a participant; so you need to provide a `FlowSession` for node `M`.
2. Since you pass a `FlowSession` for node `M`, then there should be a responder flow where node `M` calls `ReceiveFinalityFlow`; otherwise your initiator flow will hang because `FinalityFlow` will execute a `send()` to send the transaction to `M`, while `M` doesn't have a `receive()` call (which `ReceiveFinalityFlow` executes).
3. You can achieve the requirement that you're asking for by calling `ReceiveFinalityFlow` and set the input parameter `statesToRecord` to `NONE`; by default, that parameter is set to `ONLY_RELEVANT` (see flow definition [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L282)). The various types of `StatesToRecord` are explained [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/node/ServiceHub.kt#L91-L105).
4. Your responder flow must have an `if` statement, if `getOurIdentity()` is node `M`, then call `ReceiveFinalityFlow` with `statesToRecord == NONE` (because you don't want `M` to record the state), if it's node `D` then call `ReceiveFinalityFlow` with `statesToRecord == RELEVANT` (because you want `D` to record the state).
5. Please note that just because you wrote a responder a certain way, doesn't guarantee that node `M` will execute your version; writing a responder flow is usually the responsibility of the other node; their developers can write their own version of the responder in which they call `ReceiveFinalityFlow` with `statesToRecord == RELEVANT` (meaning node `M` will register the resulting state). Read the first **This is not true** in [this article](https://www.corda.net/blog/corda-flow-responder-wrong-assumptions/).
6. Once you implement the above, please write a flow test that checks that node `M`:

   - Didn't register the resulting transaction in its transaction storage
   - Didn't register the resulting state in its vault
7. The reason I'm asking you to do this is because I noticed in Corda's code the following:

   - `ReceiveFinalityFlow` calls `ReceiveTransactionFlow` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/FinalityFlow.kt#L285)
   - `ReceiveTransactionFlow` calls `ResolveTransactionFlow` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/flows/ReceiveTransactionFlow.kt#L50)
   - `ResolveTransactionFlow` overrides `statesToRecord` from `NONE` to `RELEVANT` [here](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/7dc8aa8f7c182598218d676afe1e248f5cf77e84/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/internal/ResolveTransactionsFlow.kt#L66-L69) and this statement has me worried; I just want to make sure that when you set `statesToRecord` to `NONE` in `ReceiveFinalityFlow` for node `M`, it doesn't record the transaction or the state

Let me know how things go.

Also to query by account, read in [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-r3s-accounts-library-be5ac7f0ba54) the below 2 sections:

1. Search for **Finally, how do you query the vault by account?**
2. Also read **This is very important!**

Comment: Hello Adel, thank you very much. It worked.
I checked node M and did not save the state.
The concern in item 7 was not confirmed. The value of NONE has been respected.